# SWT: Store GUI in XML

Tags: java, swt

Is there any chance to store GUI in a separate XML file? I think this is more readable.

I know, there's [swtxml](http://code.google.com/p/swtxml/) but I guess this is only an Eclipse plugin and not available in the Maven repositories. I would like to have it independent from any IDE because sometimes I don't use any IDE (e.g. for small changes it's faster to build on cli)

It could be a maven plugin as well, which converts the XML markup into Java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SWT itself does not support it. You need to write own code to get this done.

Comment: I don't see you asked for a library.

Comment: Not directly for a library, but for a chance to do this and I mentioned swtxml (which is a library).